# ReactJS : In react-rooter-dom, is useHistory deprecated?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Using this code :

```
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

...

```
const history = useHistory();
```

...

```
history.push("/login");
```

This error shows up :

[image]

Is useHistory obsolete ?
Or I do need to use another function ?

Comment: See specifically the section in the upgrade guide: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is depreciated in V6 of react-router. In this version to navigate use the `useNavigate` hook. Check the docs here [React Router V6 API Reference](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api).  Or more specifically the `useNavigate` hook here [React Router v6 UseNavigate Hook](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate). So like so:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const navigate = useNavigate()

navigate('/login')
```

Answer (score 0):

And if we want to pass the data along with navigation

Sending component->

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

const toComponentB=()=>{
   navigate('/componentB', {state: {id:1, name:'kunal'}});
}
```

Receiving component->

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

...

const location = useLocation();

return (
          <div>{location.state.name}</div>
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is deprecated. Instead you can use other methods such as:

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

<Navigate path="/login" />
```

Checkout the docs here for [Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.15.0/components/navigate)

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate('/login');
```

Checkout the docs here for [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.15.0/hooks/use-navigate)

Comment: Currently the same answers present here